# Question Marks In Filenames In QB64

Tags: basic, qbasic, qb64

Now, I have always known the following characters are reserved and cannot be used in a filename:

/:*?<>|"

However, there seems to be a case where the ? character (ascii 063) is being reported in filenames
that contain Unicode.

I am trying to use FindFirstFileA to get filenames in preparation to copying and renaming them but I
don't know why the function returns ? instead of Unicode.

My question is: How do I process filenames with ? in them?

```
REM program displays filenames with question marks in them.
' declare library constants.
CONST MAX_PATH = 260 ' length of an ASCIIZ string
CONST INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1 ' returned from a FindFirstFile
' declare library structures.
TYPE FILETIME
    dwLowDateTime AS _UNSIGNED LONG
    dwHighDateTime AS _UNSIGNED LONG
END TYPE
' windows structure for a FindFile
TYPE WIN32_FIND_DATAA
    dwFileAttributes AS _UNSIGNED LONG
    ftCreationTime AS FILETIME
    ftLastAccessTime AS FILETIME
    ftLastWriteTime AS FILETIME
    nFileSizeHigh AS _UNSIGNED LONG
    nFileSizeLow AS _UNSIGNED LONG
    dwReserved0 AS _UNSIGNED LONG
    dwReserved1 AS _UNSIGNED LONG
    cFileName AS STRING * MAX_PATH
    cAlternateFileName AS STRING * 14
END TYPE
' declare external libraries.
DECLARE DYNAMIC LIBRARY "kernel32"
    FUNCTION FindFirstFileA~%& (BYVAL lpFileName~%&, BYVAL lpFindFileData~%&)
    FUNCTION FindNextFileA& (BYVAL hFindFile~%&, BYVAL lpFindFileData~%&)
    FUNCTION FindClose& (BYVAL hFindFile~%&)
    FUNCTION GetLastError& ()
    FUNCTION SetCurrentDirectoryA% (f$)
END DECLARE
DIM Attribute AS INTEGER ' the attribute of a file
DIM ASCIIZ AS STRING * 260 ' a null terminated filename
DIM finddata AS WIN32_FIND_DATAA ' the windows filename stcucture
DIM Wfile.Handle AS _UNSIGNED _OFFSET ' windows file handle for FindFile
' force default path
x$ = _STARTDIR$
f$ = x$ + CHR$(0)
x = SetCurrentDirectoryA(f$)
' make filename
Var$ = "*.txt"
PRINT "Processing: "; Var$
ASCIIZ = Var$ + CHR$(0)
' start the search and store the returned windows file handle
Wfile.Handle = FindFirstFileA(_OFFSET(ASCIIZ), _OFFSET(finddata))
' check if the file handle is valid
IF Wfile.Handle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE THEN
    ' search through the filenames
    DO
        ' check directory attribute
        Attribute = finddata.dwFileAttributes
        ' make sure the file found is a file and not a directory
        IF (Attribute AND &H10) = &H0 THEN
            ' get the matching filename from the windows structure
            Filename$ = finddata.cFileName
            Filename$ = LEFT$(Filename$, INSTR(Filename$, CHR$(0)) - 1)
            ' check wildcards (ascii 063)
            Var = INSTR(Filename$, "?") ' check for a Unicode character
            IF Var THEN
                PRINT Filename$
            END IF
        END IF
        ' continue loop if more files exist in search specification
    LOOP WHILE FindNextFileA(Wfile.Handle, _OFFSET(finddata))
    ' release window file handle to structure
    x = FindClose(Wfile.Handle)
END IF
END
```

Comment: This link is to an archive with a filename with Unicode in it: http://www.qb64.net/forum/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=14458.0;attach=5681

Comment: Unicode characters that are not representable in your code page are translated to the ASCII `?` character by `FindFirstFileA` and similar "ANSI" Windows functions. To work with Unicode file names, you'd need to use a function meant for use with Unicode like `FindFirstFileW`, not one meant for use with the ANSI code page. Unfortunately, I can't provide any info about how to directly do this in QB64; it doesn't have a Unicode string type, so you might be stuck decoding 2 bytes of a `STRING` at a time to an `INTEGER` yourself, the latter of which you can then use with the `_MAPUNICODE` statement.

Comment: [`_MAPUNICODE` (statement)](http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/MAPUNICODE) will make QB64 see that Unicode character as an "extended ASCII" character code, meaning `CHR$(code)` will result in the Unicode character, not the original character assigned to that code; printing to the display surface merely requires a font that works. Any code `>127` (`>&H7F`) is typically a good choice usually. Not sure if this affects things like `LINE INPUT` and such though :(

Comment: I'm not interested in representing the characters in a Unicode filename. I merely need to retain the characters when copying the file with my code.

Comment: Then you'd still need to use the Unicode functions like `FindFirstFileW`, else you'll end up with `?` characters in the file name (printed to the screen or not). Your code also prints to the screen, which means you'll still likely need to use `_MAPUNICODE` to display the characters properly, but this will depend on the characters already mapped and the characters used in the file names.

Comment: I was unable to find useful usages of FindFirstFileW in MSDN, only FindFirstFileA for some reason.

Comment: Does it matter if I am in XP? Should I prepend the filename with \\?\

Comment: See [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) for info on the `\\?\` prefix and why it won't work for you here. I'm putting together an example for you now.

Comment: See [this paste](https://pastebin.com/zVdgsLmB) for an example of how to work with the Unicode versions of the FindFile stuff in Windows. The only problem remaining is how to distinguish between a real `?` in the filename and a Unicode character that uses `&H3F` as one of its bytes with a nonzero byte following it, and that has a simple solution: Windows (typically) runs on little endian machines, so the byte sequence `3F 00` represents `U+003F`, the Unicode code point assigned to the `?` character. If anything other than `00` comes after `3F`, then you don't have a `?` character.

Comment: Note that my Unicode-decoding functions also take into account invalid UTF-16LE byte sequences, replacing them with `U+FFFD`. The most appropriate equivalent of this character when working solely with ASCII-based text is `?`, which is why the ANSI versions of the FindFile functions yield that character instead, leading to your confusing output.

Comment: I've uploaded to my Dropbox account a ZIP file containing the above paste in a .BAS file and two sample text files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/34tt08y5mst6alr/wildcard.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thank you! Hadn't thought to convert ascii to wide before calling FindFirstFileW.. Does .finddata.cFilename need to be string*520 to support twice the bytes?

Comment: Why doesn't FindFirstFileW return .cAlternateFilename in WIN32_FIND_DATAW then? I need to open the longfilename for output.

Comment: Perhaps you're dealing with this: _If a file has a long file name, the complete name appears in the `cFileName` member, and the 8.3 format truncated version of the name appears in the `cAlternateFileName` member. **Otherwise, `cAlternateFileName` is empty.** ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740(v=vs.85).aspx))_ In my case, I created a `foo.txt` file with no Unicode chars and the result was a `cAlternateFilename` member with length=0.

Comment: And if my filename has Unicode characters? I can open a ascii filled .cFilename from FindfirstFileA but not FindFirstFileW.. Also, I need to convert the Unicode to Ascii but I don't have a Sub UnicodeToAscii$() either, so I am puzzled.

Comment: I included a `UnicodeToEscape$` function that allows you to display something like `ñ` as `{\u00F1}`. It's a poor solution that allows for ASCII-only output, but it's perhaps the best option. The `_MAPUNICODE` functionality limits you to a single-byte character set, and there is no way to built-in print an arbitrary Unicode character in QB64, even if you can load a proper font and everything, which is why I chose the ASCII-only "escaped" output. Filenames like `traduçao.log` will display as `tradu{\u00E7}ao.log`.

Comment: You could create your own `PrintUnicode` sub that uses the `_MAPUNICODE` statement to swap non-ASCII characters for printing them, but QB64 has no way to deal with Unicode at all other than `_MAPUNICODE`. You're essentially on your own here, creating your own encoding/decoding routines (perhaps using `WideCharToMultiByte` and `MultiByteToWideChar` Windows APIs).

Comment: You're right. There's no way to change the Ascii chart for printing without _MAPUNICODE. I wrote my own UnicodeToAscii$ function. Will look at WideCharToMultiByte.

Comment: I'm trying to get WideCharToMultiByte to work but all I get is an error x57.. Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on how you called the function; 0x57 is [`ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx).